# google map marker image sprite

Tags: google-maps-api-3, sprite

This is my first post here, hope someone can help.

I am building a mapping website using google maps.

The map shows upto 14 different icons based on a type category
I understand the theory of sprite images and the reduction in server calls these have so I have one image conating all the markers.

Question:
How do I set the position of the sprite, but only call the image once?
I have seen this post 
[Google map marker sprite image position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785226/google-map-marker-sprite-image-position)

but that only shows changing the image for one marker

This is the code

```
 //set the image once
var img = {
    url:'images/site/type_sprite.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(32,32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0)
};

idx = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
     lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lt"));
     lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("ln"));
     var type = markers[i].getAttribute("typ");

     if ((lat < latUpper && lat > latLower) && (lng < lngUpper && lng > lngLower) && (jQuery.inArray(type,filter_arr)>=0)) {

             //change the position of the icon sprite depending on type
             switch(type) {
                  case 'AA':
                    img(origin, new google.maps.Point(0,0));
                    break;
                case 'AC':
                    img(origin = new google.maps.Point(0, 42));
                    break;
                  case 'ACF':
                    img(origin= new google.maps.Point(0,84));
                    break;
                  default:
                    img(origin= new google.maps.Point(0,0));
            }
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("nme");
            //var icon = 'images/pins/' + type + '.png';
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                title: name,
                icon: img
            });
        //add to valid array
        markersArray.push(marker);

        //build infowindow string
        str = '<div class="iw_h">' + id + ' ' + name + '</div>';
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, str);
        bounds.extend(point);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        idx++;
    }
} //end of loop
}
```

If I put the code

```
    var img = {
    url:'images/site/type_sprite.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(32,32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0)
};
```

inside the loop, doesn't that mean the image is repeatedly downloaded (and it will be a bigger image than an individual icon) thus defeating the object of using a sprite?

This is the site btw
http://www.searchforsites.co.uk/full_screen.php

Comment: If the browser does the right thing, it should use the sprite image from the cache and only download it once.  [This issue in the Google Maps API issue list](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4359) has an example selecting different pieces out of a  sprite (I never looked at the performance)