# Is it advisable to use sprites for Google maps markers?

Tags: google-maps, web-applications, loading, css-sprites

I am trying to lessen the loading time of the website I am developing and used sprites to my left panel images used for navigation. As for the Google maps, it loads the map images by itself. Would it be better if I also use sprites in the markers so as to help reduce the loading time? I pin about 20 to 30 markers per page load.

Answer (score 0):

> var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("path/sprite.png", new google.maps.Size(12, 20), new google.maps.Point(100, 34));

it was answered here :

[Google map marker sprite image position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785226/google-map-marker-sprite-image-position)